# How to identify which page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single JS file where I do all of my JS logic.

I need a way to identify which page is loaded. For example, if the user loads the home page, `"home"` should be passed to the JS file. If the user loads the profile page, `"profile"` should be passed to the JS file.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

What I thought of doing was adding a variable called `page` that I would set in each page's `<script>` tag, like so:

```
<script>
    window.page = 'home';
</script>
```

How would I then access this in my JS file (and make sure that the variable exists and is set, otherwise set it to null)?

Comment: you need to include the js file after the statement and it will be accessible you do not need to pass it anywhere, apart from this you can use `SessionStorage` too for this purpose

Comment: How can I, in my main JS file, check if the variable exists and, if not, set it to null?

Comment: If I try doing `var page = typeof page !== 'undefined' ? page : null;` in my main JS file, it returns `null` every time.

Comment: remove `var` from your statement you do not need to redeclare it , just declare it once in top of the page and initialize `<script>
    var page = 'home';
</script>` and write `page = typeof page !== 'undefined' ? page : null;` inside your script file that you will include

Comment: What do you mean "just declare it once in top of the page"? Where? Just `var page;`?

Comment: Does each page have a specific url in the browser? Why dont you just slice the path off the end of the url to find out what page your on?

Comment: Basically, youd have one global method that would run on every page. When it runs it would get the current address in the url bar, then do some string manipulation to find out where it is

Answer (score 0):

your thought will work.

If you have a test.js file which contains `console.log(page);`
then you can add in your pages:

index:

```
<script>
    var page = 'index';
</script>
<script src='test.js'></script>
```

home:

```
<script>
    var page = 'home';
</script>
<script src='test.js'></script>
```

and see the results.

However, you can get the url of your current page with `window.location` object

try this in you js file:

```
console.log(window.location.pathname);
console.log(window.location.href);
```

you can check for more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

I hope that helps :)

Comment: You forgot to answer this part: "How would I then access this in my JS file (and make sure that the variable exists and is set, otherwise set it to null)?"

Comment: yes that was not clear I 'm sorry. Javascript script tags are executed in the order they share all variables decleared in each. So, if you do the first approach (your example, you declare the variable `page` and set it to each value. Then you declare another script tag with reference your js file. This file now has the variable `page` declared from the previous script tag and it has the value from each page. You can test it and see :)

Comment: this variable will never have a null value though. It is not the best approach I recommend to use `window.location` object. It is a built in object in javascript that can help you with this kind of info :)